# TCP as connection protocol questions

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask, so forgive me if it isn't.

I'm writing computer monitoring software that needs to connect to a server. The server may send out relatively urgent messages, such as sound or cancel an alarm, and the client may send out data about the computer, such as screenshots. The data that the client sends isn't too critical on timing, but shouldn't be more than a two minutes late.

It is essential to the software that portforwarding need not be set up, and it is assumed that the internet connection will be done through a wireless router that has NAT almost all the time.

My idea is to have a TCP connection initiated from the client, and use that to transfer data. Ideally, I would have no data being sent when it is not needed, but I believe this to be impossible. Would sending the equivalent of a ping every now and again keep the connection alive, and what sort of bandwidth would it use if this program was running all the time on the computer? In addition, would it be possible to reduce the header size for these keep-alives?

Before I start designing the communication and programming, is this plan for connection flawed? Are there better alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You do not need to send 'ping' data to keep the connection alive, the TCP stack does this automatically; one reason for sending 'ping' data would be to detect a connection close on the client side - typically you only find out something has gone wrong when you try and read/write from the socket. There may be a way to change various time-outs so you can detect this condition faster.

2) In general while TCP provides a stream-oriented error free channel, it makes no guarantees about timeliness, if you are using it on the internet it is even more unpredictable.

3) For applications such as this (I hope you are making it for ethical purposes) - I would tend to use TCP, since you don't want a situation where the client receives a packet to raise an alarm but misses that one that turns it off again.

Comment: The TCP stack does not send pings automatically unless you tell it to, by enabling keepalive on the socket. It is disabled by default.

Comment: Don't worry, all transparent and ethical (and will be released under GPL). If I understood part 1 correctly, I can just open a connection, leave it for hours, and then should something urgent need to be done—like the alarm—it has instant access?

Comment: as EJP points out you need to turn enable keep-alive; Yes you can connect and leave the channel open, and send data when you need to, however, what if just before you are sending your connection goes down? Your best case scenario will be the message will get to the other end by with the available latency on the network - your worst cases are, latency goes up, latency goes up so bad you get timeouts and need to issue reconnections, or the other end goes down and you will have to make several attempts, I would tend to take the average case but it is good to keep the worst case scenarios in mind.